# a strange error

Tags: visual-c++

i define method in my class and this error occurred.
error C2371: redefinition; different basic types

my Method:

```
Buffer::SetSourceCode(string str)
    {
        SourceCode=str;
    }
```

and my class:

```
class Buffer
{
    string SourceCode;
    int Index;
    int PreIndex;
    int Length;
    public:
        void SetSourceCode(string str);
        void SetSourceFromFile();
        string CopyString();
        string Copy();
        void SetPreIndex(void);
        void IncreaseIndex();
        void ReturnBack();
        bool IsEnd();
        char ReadChar();
        Buffer(void);
        ~Buffer(void);
    };
```

what is error ?
thanks.

Comment: Did you mean `std::string`?  And where'd the return type go?

Answer (score 0):

As far a i know, Buffer is a "reserved" (existing) name for a class in Visual-C++.  Your class tries to redefine an existing type.

See
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.buffer.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try to include headers:

```
#include <string>
using namespace std;
```